# How to Focus inthe First Cell of a Newly-Added Row in a dojox.grid.DataGrid

Tags: dojox.grid, dojo

I am adding a new blank row to a dojox.grid.DataGrid, and want to focus in the first cell of the new row.

I add the row by calling:

```
var new_row = {},  
attributes = store.getAttributes( items[0] );

dojo.forEach( attributes, function( attribute )
{                   
    dojo.forEach( attributes, function( attribute )
    {
        new_row[ attribute ] = null;
    } );

} );

store.newItem( new_row );
```

I believe the following code will do the focusing:

```
grid.focus.setFocusIndex( row_index, 0 );
grid.edit.setEditCell( grid.focus.cell, row_index );
```

But I cannot figure out how to only call this code after the grid has re-rendered. I guess I need to connect to an event. However, I can't see a likely event to use. onNew() seems to be called before the new row is added.

Here's a JSFiddle which gets as close as I can to a solution. http://jsfiddle.net/xDUpp/ (comment out the line marked edit and it adds the new row)

Thanks

Comment: Hi, checkout my solution in the answer, hope that helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Which version of Dojo are you interested in?

The Dojo API differs between ver. in this matter.

Look at:
http://jsfiddle.net/keemor/xDUpp/11/

After store is modified grid needs a little time to rebuild itself, so setFocusIndex & setEditCell must also be delayed to work:

```
store.onNew = function( new_item ) {
    var rowIndex = new_item._0;                    
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        grid.focus.setFocusIndex( rowIndex, 0 );
        grid.edit.setEditCell( grid.focus.cell, rowIndex );
    },10);    

};
```

Greetz

Comment: Thanks keemor. I have added a JSFiddle to the initial post based on the one you supplied.